# Python reading a file and making a list of lists needing two delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read a file with many lines and turn the contents into a list with rows being lists and columns either strings, numeric types or other lists so that I may access the individual elements and perform computations later.

Given a file containing:

```
x1 1 (x1 y1 0.5) (x1 y2 0.5)
x2 5 (x2 y1 1.0) (x3 y1 1.0) (x4 y1 1.0)
```

After reading the file and transforming it to a list of lists it should be:

```
input = [
  ['x1', 1, ['x1', 'y1', 0.5], ['x1', 'y2', 0.5]]
  ['x2', 5, ['x2', 'y1', 1.0], ['x3', 'y1', 1.0], ['x4', 'y1', 1.0]]
]
```

I've tried using a csv.reader() and delimit by parentheses groups first then go back and delimit by whitespace but it got messy and incorrect from what I was wanting. So i'm thinking I should try regex but i'm not to familiar with it.

Comment: You try to replace parenthesis with quotes, and delimit on spaces?

Comment: @SunnyPatel No I have not. But that sounds pretty reasonable. For some reason I was going about it trying to delimit twice. I'll give it a try

Comment: Does it need to be nested as [x,[y,z],[a,b]], or can you work with [[x],[y,z],[a,b]]?

Comment: @G.Anderson Doesn't need to be nested. Just in a way thats easier to read in accessing the elements I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the smallest amount of work, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to help out along with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). Works with both Python 2 and 3

```
from ast import literal_eval
from re import sub

def clean_and_parse(line):
  line = line.strip().replace(' ', ',')
  return literal_eval(sub(r"([a-z]\d+)", r'"\1"', line))

with open("somefile", "r") as f:
  inp = f.readlines()

parsed = map(clean_and_parse, inp)
print(list(parsed))
```

> ```
> [('x1', 1, ('x1', 'y1', 0.5), ('x1', 'y2', 0.5)),
>  ('x2', 5, ('x2', 'y1', 1.0), ('x3', 'y1', 1.0), ('x4', 'y1', 1.0))]
> ```

This basically replaces all the spaces with commas (`' '` => `','`) and quotes all of your text (`x1` => `'x1'`). Then it splits the string into lines and feeds them into `literal_eval` and pushed into a list, line-by-line.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4 and this works in your example, but I'm trying to let inp = open(somefile, 'r').read() and I get a syntax error and shows the " char prepended to all the strings. I assumed this would work because read() returns the entire file as a string?

Comment: Updated my answer with the information from your environment. You can use `.readlines()` to get the input as a list of lines as strings, but it preserves the newline character, so that needs to be `strip`ped.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser:

```
import re
line = "x1 1 (x1 y1 0.5) (x1 y2 0.5)"
stack = []
for token in re.findall('[()]|[\w.]+', line):
    if token == '(':
        stack.append([])
    elif token == ')':
        c = stack.pop()
        stack[-1].append(c)
    else:
        try:
            token = float(token)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        stack[-1].append(token)
tokens = stack.pop()
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs?

```
x='x2 5 (x2 y1 1.0) (x3 y1 1.0) (x4 y1 1.0)'
[i.replace(')',"").split() for i in x.split('(')]
[['x2', '5'], ['x2', 'y1', '1.0'], ['x3', 'y1', '1.0'], ['x4', 'y1', '1.0']]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match OP's expected output?

Comment: True, but I asked if it was a required output, and OP said _"Doesn't need to be nested. Just in a way thats easier to read in accessing the elements I suppose"_